# Incorrect Sql query for date

Tags: sql, vba, filter

I have an SQL query I am working through excel 2013 accessing an access db. Query is working correctly except it isn't filtering out the date. It should have zero results but has 23 instead. I have hand-checked the db to ensure the correct record count. I feel like I am missing something obvious, but this query is pulling results from the date field from before 07/01/2015 and I have tried reversing the relation operator ">".

```
date_ = "07/01/2015"
'SQL query
strSql = "SELECT [Field1] FROM [Table1] WHERE [Field1] like '%" & field1 & "%' AND [" & x & "] = true AND [Date] >= " & date_ & ";"
```

This is the printed Sql query:

```
SELECT [Field1] FROM [Table1] WHERE [Field1] like '%255793%' AND [field2] = true AND [Date] >= 7/1/2015;
```

Ideas?

And please let me know if more code is needed.

Thanks!

Comment: @Stidgeon I have checked for that. Earliest date for result it is pulling up is "6/16/2014" [without quotes] which is copied directly from field. I believe my date query matches this format though I know this field is labeled "Date/Time" and the date_ data member is declared a date variable.

Comment: as an update, changing the relationship operator for the date field to <= produces zero results, even when there should be some. I feel like this must be some kind of trivial thing such as formatting, as Stidgeon said. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **#mm/dd/yyyy#** as the date literal format (regardless of which order is used in your regional settings) so, assuming you were looking for 1st July 2015, use this fragment:

```
"[Date] >= #" & Format(date, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#;"
```

Comment: Thanks barrowc, this has solved my problem. I am not sure why the '#'s are necessary, will look up. Thanks again!